# overwrite git's history with commits in refs/replace

Tags: git, replace, refs, git-filter-repo

I ran git filter-repo on a repository to remove some secrets using the `--replace-text` flag.

I admit I don't understand the tool completely, and found out after I pushed the changes to remote (gitlab) that none of the replacements are present on the original commits SHAs.

When I checked for the changes in local again, I see the changes/text removal using `git show <SHA-1>` with the ref as `(replaced)`, and the updates to the original commits were made in identical commits SHAs under `refs/replace` .

I read the `git-filter-repo` and `git-replace` documentation but the info there was pretty dense.

I did come across `git-filter-repo`'s `--replace-refs delete-no-add` flag after, and realized that might've helped me before.

So now, what is the best way to overwrite the original git history with refs from `refs/replace/`?

Thanks in advance.